# Strange and unpredictable rounding behaviour in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I am writing a web app that is converting SQL data in the form of text (dollar amounts) to numbers, then totalling. However, I've come across only certain values that round very oddly!

I have a JSFiddle to show this (with more values than below) as well as sample code below, using text vars as I would be pulling from SQL data.  JSFiddle [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/0pd965v2/)

I've done what I've seen recommended here by various people and multiplied values by 100 to work with integers only - hoping to avoid rounding issues. I've tried various combinations of Number() and toFixed etc but can't seem to get a handle on the best way to avoid rounding issues in JS.
Most values are fine, but I accidentally came across '129.42' being an issue.  I have no idea what other numbers might also cause problems leaving my app totally unreliable!!  This is very peculiar behaviour!?

HTML:

```
<html>
<body id='body'>
Example of NASTY rounding in JavaScript:
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var ary = [ '129.42', '129.45', '125.42', '125.45', '130.42'];
var div;
for (var x in ary) {
  var text = ary[x];
  var num = parseInt(Number(text)*100);

  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Original "text" number: '+text;
  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(div);

  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Multiply by 100 and Converted to Integer: '+num+'<br><br>';
  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(div); 
}
```

The above results in:

Example of NASTY rounding in JavaScript:

Original "text" number: 129.42
Multiply by 100 and Converted to Integer: 12941

Original "text" number: 129.45
Multiply by 100 and Converted to Integer: 12944

Original "text" number: 125.42
Multiply by 100 and Converted to Integer: 12542

Original "text" number: 125.45
Multiply by 100 and Converted to Integer: 12545

Original "text" number: 130.42
Multiply by 100 and Converted to Integer: 13041

Comment: eg `12941.999999999998`, `12944.999999999998`, `13041.999999999998` for 1, 2, and 5. If you want to round, *use round*, `parseInt` will discard decimal places.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for reasons why using for-in with an array is bad

Comment: Thanks @Jack Bashford.  I was being lazy ;v)

Comment: @CertainPerformance where is this duplicated?  I'd like to understand why it's happening - if possible.

Comment: See the link at the top of the question.